# Connect C# bot with a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, soapui, bots

I have a bot on Visual Studio with C# and I need connect it with a web service. I found [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250965.aspx) and followed all the steps, but changing the URL of the step 3 for the URL of the web service that I need (http://fx.currencysystem.com/webservices/CurrencyServer4.asmx). This doesn't generate any error but I don't know how make calls from the bot to the web service or test if the connection was successful.

Can anyone help me or tell me how make it? I searched a lot but I can't find documentation to do it.

Comment: SOAP services do things differently from REST services. You might consider looking at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-web-service-using-soap-request/ as an example of how to make a SOAP request.

Answer (score 0):

In step 3, the only thing you did was add a reference (download the dll containing all methods and objects needed for your tests).

Now you need to call those methods in your main program